# do_action( 'init' ) in wp-settings.php breaks my website. All plugins and themes disabled

Tags: errors, configuration, init

As the title says, do_action( 'init' ) in wp-settings.php breaks my website. All plugins and themes have been disabled.

Basically if I comment out line 308 which is simply `do_action( 'init' );` then the site works fine, but if I enable that line, I see just a white page, no HTML in the source at all. I've disabled all plugins and themes. How do I continue troubleshooting from here?

UPDATE: The problem is due to a bad cron job, the output of my list of cronjobs is here:

```
FUNCTION                        ARGUMENTS               SHEDULE TIME (H)
wp_scheduled_auto_draft_delete  array ( )               Once Daily  24
wp_scheduled_delete             array ( )               Once Daily  24
publish_future_post             array ( 0 => 43169, )   not-set
wp_version_check                array ( )               Twice Daily 12
wp_update_plugins               array ( )               Twice Daily 12
wp_update_themes                array ( )               Twice Daily 12
do_pings                        array ( )               not-set
sm_build_cron                   array ( )               not-set
```

The function sm_build_cron is from the plugin google-sitemap-generator and the function referenced it:
Action:

```
//WP Cron hook
add_action('sm_build_cron', array('GoogleSitemapGeneratorLoader', 'CallBuildSitemap'),1,0);
```

Function:

```
function CallBuildSitemap() {  
    if(GoogleSitemapGeneratorLoader::LoadPlugin()) {  
        $gs = &GoogleSitemapGenerator::GetInstance();  
        $gs->BuildSitemap();
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have [debugging enabled](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Comment: It's not the `init` action that's breaking your site; rather, it's your Theme or a Plugin that is outputting code that produces a fatal error on `init`. Enable debugging, and report the **fatal error** that is generated.

Comment: I enabled it, and nothing changed. No output, just a blank page, nothing in the source of the page either.

Comment: Thanks Chip. I had deleted every plugin file and theme file from the server. It still happens. Is there a way to scrub the old plugin info from the database?

Comment: I put this code in my config file http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#Example_wp-config.php_for_debugging and still no output.

Comment: This is so odd. I've deleted all extra tables added to my database, deleted all themes other than stock, and deleted all plugins. Still the same error occurs.

Comment: You should enable error_reporting in your site .

Comment: Thanks. I've narrowed the action down to a command in default-filters.php. I commented every line out that begins with `add_action( 'init',` from this file, and the site works now. I'm going to go one by one and find the offending code.

Comment: It's line 237, `add_action( 'init', 'wp_cron' );`, the line above that is `if ( !defined( 'DOING_CRON' ) )`. If I disable line 237 it works fine. So it's a cron issue, I believe possibly relating to a plugin that posts missed scheduled posts.

Comment: The blank white page is due to some error in wp-cron. I've added this line to my wp-config.php `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', 'true');` and everything works fine now. 

Now I have to find an alternative cron manager.

Comment: Now it's about finding that cron "job" that breaks your site. [Use this Gist-Plugin as starting point](https://gist.github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/987128) and update your question with the info.

Comment: Could you please just ***edit and update*** your question and add that as plain text instead of an image?

Comment: Sure, the problem was that it was a table, and the table doesn't paste well. I'll update the first post with the table information. @kaiser

Comment: Updated @kaiser

Comment: @Branndon Much better :) Now we just need the source of `sm_build_cron()`. Might want to search your plugins or theme. If you can't cross file search your code base, then just deactivate one plugin after the other (step by step) and in between just run that script to see if that callback disappears. If it does, you've identified the plugin. Then search this plugins code base and post the function source in your question as edit.

Comment: Pinging @kaiser

Comment: @Branndon Now pinging back: And what it is inside those methods? You have a link to source code? Note that I'm not trying to help you with the actual problem, but with making a question that someone can answer.

Comment: The coding term "methods" is new to me. Here is the file in question: http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/google-sitemap-generator/tags/3.2.9/sitemap.php

I understand the help, thank you. I would like the answer to be available to all too. @kaiser

Comment: @Branndon Please take a look on php.net about OOP/Object Oriented Programming, classes and methods (the name for functions inside classes).

Comment: Thanks for all the help on this @kaiser. Now that I know that a method is a function inside a class, I understand your previous comment. Before digging in to all of this, I believe the problem is that my cron list is just too large... I have nearly 40,000 scheduled posts, and I think that's too large for cron to handle. I think I'll start a 2nd topic about what to do with this many scheduled posts in cron.

Comment: Please do not use comments for extensive discussion, they aren't meant for it. Edit post with updates or find some time and connect in chat.